iPhone shortcut: How to add and display a contact
I’m trying to add a contact, when I use the Add New Contact action, a popup with fields is shown, but once you press done, it disappears. What I’m trying to figure out is how to:

Add a new contact
Display the contact that was just created. I don’t want to search for that contact because there might be duplicates from previous contacts.

How can I achieve this? (I’ve gone through the docs and have been smashing my head trying to figure this out)
